# How with laravel factory add data to related table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-factory

In laravel 8 app I add dummy data for ads table with factory:

```
$ads = Ad::factory()->count(10)->expired($year, $month)->create([
]);
```

And with database/factories/AdFactory.php:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Config;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Models\Ad;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use \Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Services\SlugService;

class AdFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = Ad::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        $text= $this->faker->text;
        $slugValue = SlugService::createSlug(Ad::class, 'slug', $text);

        return [
            'title' => $text,
            'ad_token' => $text,
            'slug' => $slugValue,
            'phone_display' => (rand(1, 3) == 1),
            'has_locations' => (rand(1, 4) == 1),
            'status' => 'A',
            'price' => mt_rand(10, 500),
            'ad_type' => (rand(1, 2) == 1 ? 'B' : 'S'),
            'description' => $this->faker->paragraphs(rand(1, 4), true),
            'creator_id' => rand(1, 5),
        ];
    }

    public function expired($year, $month)
    {
        return $this->state(function (array $attributes) use($year, $month) {
            $dateStr= $year.'-'.str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).'-01';
            $startDate= Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $dateStr);
            return [
                'expire_date' => $this->faker->dateTimeInInterval($startDate, '1 month', Config::get('app.timezone'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            ];
        });
    }
}
```

It works ok, but I wonder how can I add dummy data into related ad_categories( has ad_id field ) ?
definition methods returns ad object(with new id) and where can I get access to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make an CategoryFactory class and create Dummy categories, then select a random category as category_id

**For one-to-many relationship**

```php
    //...
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            //your code
            'creatory_id' => $this->faker->randomElement(Category::all())['id'],
        ];
    }
    //...
```

or

```php
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            //your code
            'creatory_id' => factory(Category::class)->create()->id,
        ];
    }
```

The second solution will create a new category for each Ad

**For many-to-many relationship**

```php
namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\AdFactory;
use App\Models\Category;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class AdFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Ad::class;

    /**
     * Configure the model factory.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function configure()
    {
        return $this->afterCreating(function (Ad $newAd) { 
            $adCategory = AdCategory::factory()->count(1)->create([ 'ad_id' => $newAd->id, 'category_id' => $this->faker->randomElement(Category::all())['id']); 
        }); 
    }

    // ...
}
```

For more information visit https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#factory-callbacks

and https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#polymorphic-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Your examples are not clear . What is "creatory_id" ?
I will detalize:
With ads table I also have categories table with id, name fields.

I need to add dummy data into ad_categories (fields ad_id, category_id),
WHERE ad_id - REF TO NEWLY CREATED ad, 
category_id - ref to one of existing category.

Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I thought it was a one-to-many relationship. But you can relate an ad to a random dummy category

Comment: Sorry, not clear. Coold you please give example? and I can not catch how can I get and use NewlyAd.id ?

Comment: Thanks! I made it with some fixing your code :         return $this->afterCreating(function (Ad $newAd) { // Ad model is returned here
            $adCategory = AdCategory::factory()->count(1)->create([
                'ad_id' => $newAd->id,
                'category_id' => $this->faker->randomElement(Category::all())['id'],

            ]);
        });
Please edit it and I will ecept your answer!

Comment: @mstdmstd Done!